# php подключиться к accdb

Tags: php7, ms-access, denwer

сервер denwer на винде 7. в php.ini `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll`
файл base2020.accdb. Подключаюсь:

`$dbaccess = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" .$dbpath. ";Uid=; Pwd=;");`

ошибка:
`SQLSTATE[HY024] SQLDriverConnect: -1023 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.`

`$dbpath="db/base2020.accdb"`
`file_exists($dbpath) = true;`

как подключиться?

Comment: в `$dbpath` что?

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил в вопрос

Comment: попробуйте указать полный путь до файла и заменить слэш в пути с прямого на обратный

Comment: @ArchDemon вряд ли проблема в пути. в той же папке файл .sqlite нормально открывается через `new SQLite3($dbpath);`. Обратный слэш не помог